# Three.js, identify vertices on the "upper faces" of ring

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, geometry

I'm currently working on a project that involves creating various kind of "rings" using Three.js.
My "rings" are generated using an algorithm I wrote myself. Basically I define 4 sections positioned at π, π/2, 3π/2 and 2π and then interpolate a ring from those sections using quadratic bezier curves. So far this works pretty well. What I would like to be able to do next, is to programmatically determine which vertices are on the "upper surface" of the ring.

How would I be able to achieve something like that?

[image]

The 4 shapes on the left are my 4 sections. The ring on the right is generated using those 4 sections

Comment: By 'ring' do you mean 'torus'? I can't quite picture your scenario.

Comment: Sorry I admit my explanations aren't very clear. I added a screenshot to my questions.

Comment: What is an "upper surface"? What are "upper faces?. By "sections", do you mean "cross-sections"?

Comment: By sections I do indeed mean cross-sections, by upper surface/face I mean the faces that are on the "outside" of my ring. Like when you wear a ring, there is a surface that you see and a surface that your finger is in contact with, I want to be able to get the surface that you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are several ways to do this, in order to plan an optimal way we have to know more about your scenario... but besides that, why not

- go by vertice index if you have the same amount of vertices for every section? (like, every vertex where % == 2 or 3 is on the outside)
- calculate a distance from the vertex to the ring's center and see if it's over a certain treshhold (i.e. those further away are visible)
- Figure out whether the vertex normal is in a somewhat similar direction like the radius or distance you calculated.

Up to you... if you're not satisfied some thorough explanation of your scenario might help a bit more.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the indices like you suggested.